# If User disable cookies my project session stop working

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

My project in codeigniter and problem is that if some user disable cookie then he can't login in to my project.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: So try to put a message that says you must active your cookie

Comment: You'd have to send the session id back and forth so that the server knows which session to use when a request is made.

Comment: I want to achieve it without cookies because I want that if user not willing to enable cookies then he/she can also login

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to work with customer session when cookie is turned off entirely, 
you can use:
`ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", 0);` //  will force the appendage of a session id to each url

However, this way has it's own disadvantages, e.g. in case not using secure connection (e.g. http) session id can be stollen and etc.

Comment: This should be avoided at all costs, due to many security problems (not just session hijacking as you indicate, but also fixation attacks). It's hard to get it right.

Comment: Sure, thanks, I have found your answer about fixation attacks.

Comment: @sergio is there any library to work with session in codeigniter without using cookies